# Peewee returns multiple Objects during an Inner Join

Tags: python, peewee

```
class Parent(BaseModel):
    name = peewee.CharField()

class Child(BaseModel):
    name = peewee.CharField()
    parent = peewee.ForeignKeyField(Parent, related_name='children')

parent = Parent.create(name="Parent1")
child1 = Child.create(name="Child1", parent=parent)
chilld2 = Child.create(name="Child2", parent=parent)

query = (Parent.select()
        .join(Child))

for p in query:
    print p.name
    for c in p.children:
        print "\t",c.name
```

This results in the following output:

```
Parent1
    Child1
    Child2
Parent1
    Child1
    Child2
```

I was expected this:

```
Parent1
    Child1
    Child2
```

It would seem that I am iterating over a SQL result set as opposed to a object in the ORM sense. Given that there is only one "Parent object", from an ORM perspective, in the query, how can I modify my query or my iteration over the query to get the expected results?

I want to return the query to my template like in the peewee example app and just iterate over it to display the object, but if I do that it will display the same object twice (or n times for n number of related children).

I know I can do the following:

```
p = query.get()
print p.name
for c in p.children:
    print "\t", c.name
```

But when I have multiple parents and just want to loop through them all, I can't identify how many parents there are. The `count` method of query returns the count of the result set, as opposed to the count of them number of parent objects there are.

This is also a work around:

```
pars = []
for p in query:
    if p not in pars:
        pars.append(p)

for p in pars:
    print p.name
    for c in p.children:
        print "\t", c.name
```

Comment: Try `query = (Child.select()
        .join(Parent))` and read about [join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29). There are different kinds of join. I think, the "Natural join" will return the set you are after. Appears like you are more knowledgeable on that field.

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems with your code.

The first is that, even though you've joined on `Child`, calling `parent.children` will execute an extra, separate query.

Because of the first problem, you're mistaking what the outer loop is doing, which is just giving you the Parent portion of Parent1+Child1, Parent1+Child2.

To fix this you can do use `prefetch` or `aggregate_rows`:

```
# Execute a single query and de-dupe the duplicated parent rows.
query = Parent.select(Parent, Child).join(Child).aggregate_rows()
for parent in query:
    print parent.name
    for child in parent.children:
        print childname

# Execute a query for each joined table. Generally more efficient
# than aggregate_rows().
query = prefetch(Parent.select(), Child)
for parent in query:
    print parent.name
    for child in parent.children_prefetch:  # NOTE the `_prefetch`
        print child.name
```

This is documented extensively: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#avoiding-n-1-queries

Comment: Hi Coleifer. No wonder my queries were slow :). The following: `query = Parent.select(Parent, Child).join(Child).aggregate_rows()` results in `AttributeError: 'SelectQuery' object has no attribute 'aggregate_rows'`. Any idea why? The prefetch is working for me. In the documentation, you stated that that "Note that neither the User query, nor the Tweet query contained a JOIN clause. When using prefetch() you do not need to specify the join." I need to join table A to B, and table B to tables X and Z. However Table X and Z both have an FK to B and A, but I want the join to be on B.id.

Comment: I was able to `for a in peewee.prefetch(A.select(), B.select(), X.select(), Y.select())` successfully.

Comment: You may be using an older version of peewee, so you can try upgrading. If prefetch works, that's a good option, too.